# The configName must be a non-empty string in KNIME

Tags: knime

I am trying to see configuration page of the KNIME node which i just published to my KNIME analytics tool.

Getting error "Error while creating node dialog for 'Readadwords': The configName must be a non-empty string" where Readadwords is my node dialog class which i created in eclipse.

Either in my Nodemodel or Nodedialog there is not a single config and i have defaulted it some or other string value.

Can some one help me where to look to fix my error and also please let me know if i can debug my knime plugin from eclipse rather than doing it in Analytics tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is KNIME is not picking up the changes i have done to the code and i had to change version in plugin.xml file then it started working after copying new jar file to dropins folder of KNIME

Answer (score 1):

Debugging is explained in [their developer guide](https://www.knime.com/developer-guide), [this page](https://www.knime.com/test-your-node) is the most relevant for that.

When you save your settings you have not specified the key for your config, that is what this error message is about. Like in [this place](https://github.com/knime/knime-core/blob/3.4.1/org.knime.base/src/org/knime/base/node/preproc/stringreplacer/StringReplacerSettings.java#L308-L316) assuming `""` were used instead of `"colName"`, I would expect a similar error message.

Comment: Yes followed the same but getting error                                                                                !MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the key bindings from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commands' and 'org.eclipse.ui.bindings' extension point
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2017-11-20 13:42:19.131
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.knime.workbench.editor', id='knime.commands.editor.gridSettings'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2017-11-20 13:42:23.231
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/icons/full/eview16/javadoc.png

Comment: Could not create the view: org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavadocView